# SQLite table vanishes after close

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I'm currently working on an IoT core UWP app, using SQLite. I'm having a problem, where after debugging on remote Rapberry, or deploying my app to it, after clising the program, all my table vanishes.

I have some sourve code:

```
    private static SQLiteConnection DbConnection
    {
        get
        {              
            return new SQLiteConnection(
                new SQLitePlatformWinRT(),
                Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "IoTdb.sqlite"));
        }
    }

    private void createDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            db = DbConnection;
            db.TraceListener = new DebugTraceListener();
            db.CreateTable<kapu_modClass>();
            db.Close();
            //string query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + getTName(11) + " (kapuMAzon int NOT NULL, kapuMNev varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(kapuMAzon));";
            //db.Execute(query);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

While I run my code, i can create tables, get my data into it:

```
                kapu_modClass km = new kapu_modClass();
                km.kapuMAzon = 1;
                km.kapuMNev = "1";
                db.Execute("INSERT INTO " + getTName(11) + " (kapuMAzon) VALUES('" + km.kapuMAzon + "');") ;

[Table ("kapu_mod_tabla")]
public class kapu_modClass 
{
    [PrimaryKey, Column("kapuMAzon", Name = "kapuMAzon")]
    public int kapuMAzon { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255), Column("kapuMNev", Name = "kapuMNev")]
    public string kapuMNev { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works fine, until I close the app, then when I restart it, I lose everything, only the database remains.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
It seems like, it has a 2 start cicle period: on the first attempt, it makes my database, but can't opent it. On the second start the database file is there, no need to create, opens, creating the tables, and after closing the program, deletes the database created on first attempt, and back to the first cicle. On every start, all my tables are empty, tryed the db.Execute("PRAGMA TEMP_STORE=1"); command, it suppose to set my table permanent, but not working eighter.

Comment: Are you accidentally working on an in-memory database only? I.e. there is no db file on a storage medium associated? with SQLite command line tool on PC (my environment) I imagine I could see the same behaviour when starting sqlite3.exe without a file name parameter. The CLI then starts with a warning  `Connected to a transient in-memory database.`

Comment: How about suspending the app?  Is there any place you write code about delete tables?

Comment: @Yunnosch the sqlite file stays remain after I close the app, I think that suppose to be the db file. I took the example from the http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/09/08/Using-SQLite-on-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx page, they don't mention anything else to do. How can I set it to non memory database?

Comment: Also I didn't wrote anything about delete something yet, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have it, when I run in debug mode, or make a debug app package it loses everything, after generating a release app package it works fine.